# Developing maven-plugin: how to get list of direct dependencies defined in pom.xml?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am using methods **getDependencyManagement()** and **getDependencies()** of class **org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject** to get a list of dependencies of pom.xml on which the plugin is executed, but I am also getting the inherited dependencies.

How I can get a list of dependencies defined **directly** inside the pom.xml, and not any of the inherited ones.

Answer (score 1):

From the `MavenProject` class you can use the `getDependencyArtifacts()` method. Its Javadoc reads:

```
/**
 * Direct dependencies that this project has.
 * @return Set<Artifact>
 * @see #getArtifacts() to get all transitive dependencies
 */
```

Comment: in what way did it not work? Did you get an exception or just an empty set returned?